# Java get random class

Tags: java

I am trying to figure out an effective way of getting a random class from my project. There are nine different classes(ten including the startup), each one with a different behavior(which extend a declaratoid class that is used in the main function). I need to be able to have the function to run differently on each startup. What do I need to do? Edit:Thanks for the answer, but I am now running into another problem. I have to pass the result as the first parameter in another the function now.

Comment: You're probably looking for the reflection mechanism in Java.

Answer (score 3):

Create a factory method that gets a random number and creates an object based on that, in a switch:

```
public static YourInterfaceType createRandom() {
   Random r = new Random();
   switch(r.nextInt(10)) {
       case 1: return new FirstType();
       case 2: return new SecondType();
       // etc
       default: return new LastType();
   } 
}
```

**Edit** More exact definition of words. :)

Comment: Technically speaking you're not creating classes.

Comment: @aioobe I took the intent to mean instances of already defined classes. If OP provides more detail and this is off the mark, I'm happy to remove it.

Comment: He was referring to your statement `and creates a class based on that` - not true. It's creating an instance of an existing class, not creating a class.

Comment: Thank you for the answer Todd. It looks exactly like what I need.

Answer (score 0):

you could generate a random number from 1 - 9 and use a switch statement where each case calls a different class